# Filter then rank a multi-level index Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas Dataframe with two columns (Col1 and Col2) and a multi-level index (Date and Symbol) as follows:

```
                 Col1    Col2
Date     Symbol     
2015-12-01  AAA  0.45    0.53
            BBB -1.02   -0.57
            CCC -0.41    0.30
2015-11-02  AAA  0.59   -0.42
            BBB -2.16   -0.77
            CCC -1.02    1.09
2015-10-01  AAA -0.44   -0.88
            BBB  0.52    0.27
            CCC -1.76    0.63
```

Code to replicate this Dataframe is:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': ['2015-12-01']*3 + ['2015-11-02']*3 + ['2015-10-01']*3,
                    'Symbol': ['AAA','BBB','CCC']*3,
                    'Col1': 0.45,-1.02,-0.41,0.59,-2.16,-1.02,-0.44,0.52,-1.76],
                    'Col2': [0.53,-0.57,0.3,-0.42,-0.77,1.09,-0.88,0.27,0.63]},
                     ).set_index(['Date', 'Symbol'])
```

Within each date, I’m trying to select the top n rows (in this case 2) based on the largest values in Col1, and then rank those rows based on the values in Col2 (largest == 1, second largest == 2, etc). Adding the result as a column to the original Dataframe, the final Dataframe should look like the following:

```
                 Col1   Col2    Rank
Date     Symbol         
2015-12-01  AAA  0.45    0.53   1
            CCC -0.41    0.30   2
            BBB -1.02   -0.57   NaN
2015-11-02  CCC -1.02    1.09   1
            AAA  0.59   -0.42   2
            BBB -2.16   -0.77   NaN
2015-10-01  BBB  0.52    0.27   1
            AAA -0.44   -0.88   2
            CCC -1.76    0.63   NaN
```

I’ve attempted using the groupby and rank functions but I’m having difficulty getting the indexing correct.

For example, `df.reset_index().groupby(['Date'])['Col1'].nlargest(2)` yields:

```
Date         
2015-10-01  7    0.52
            6   -0.44
2015-11-02  3    0.59
            5   -1.02
2015-12-01  0    0.45
            2   -0.41
```

But I can't figure out how to rank and put the result back into the Dataframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
 df['largest'] = df.groupby(level='Date').apply(lambda x: x.Col1.nlargest(2)).reset_index(0, drop=True)
 df['ranked'] = df.groupby(level='Date').apply(lambda x: x.dropna(subset=['largest']).Col2.rank(ascending=False)).reset_index(0, drop=True)
```

to get:

```
                   Col1  Col2  largest  ranked
Date       Symbol                             
2015-12-01 AAA     0.45  0.53     0.45       1
           BBB    -1.02 -0.57      NaN     NaN
           CCC    -0.41  0.30    -0.41       2
2015-11-02 AAA     0.59 -0.42     0.59       2
           BBB    -2.16 -0.77      NaN     NaN
           CCC    -1.02  1.09    -1.02       1
2015-10-01 AAA    -0.44 -0.88    -0.44       2
           BBB     0.52  0.27     0.52       1
           CCC    -1.76  0.63      NaN     NaN
```

Comment: thank you for an elegant solution, this is exactly what I was trying to accomplish.